# Httpwebrequest upload text and images

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I want to post an ad on olx.ba using `HttpWebRequest`. To post an ad I had to log in first, so I took the cookies from that request and passed it to the request that posts the ad. Until now the ad is posted correctly, but the ad has no images.

```
public void PostProduct(Account account, Product product)
    {
        // Get login cookies
        CookieCollection cookieCollection = GetLoginCookies(account);

        request = InitializeRequest(request, "https://www.olx.ba/objava/zavrsi");

        // Set the login cookies
        foreach (Cookie c in response.Cookies)
        {
            request.CookieContainer.Add(c);
        }

        postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(UrlHelpers.ToQueryString(product));
        request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
        }

        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        // responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }
```

The website has a form for uploading the images and when i select an image to upload this is the request made by that form:

**Request headers**

```
POST /objava/upload?s=RBDQpWEcUu HTTP/1.1
Host: www.olx.ba
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 283041
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: https://www.olx.ba
X-File-Name: 2.jpg
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---WebKitFormBoundaryAczld5sbjrh0FX5q
Accept: application/json
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: https://www.olx.ba/objava
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ro;q=0.6,de;q=0.4
Cookie: xxxxx
```

**Request Payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryAczld5sbjrh0FX5q
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="2.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryAczld5sbjrh0FX5q--
```

I think the upload form is from dropzone.js if that helps in any way. How can i make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Before uoloading images as a path. Try to convert the images to byte array and then to the base64String using Convert.toBase64String method. Then post the base64 string to the website.

Thanks.

Comment: But where do I send it? I send it in the same place where i send the other data? The ad details has to go to https://www.olx.ba/objava/zavrsi and the image to https://www.olx.ba/objava/upload . Can you provide me with an exemple? Thank you!

Comment: Send  data URL of 2.jpg image in formdata. Also if everything is fine then the only thing that is bothering the server might be the **Content-Type**. Try setting **Content-Type** :multipart/form-data; instead of image/jpeg.